# Ui not updating while connecting to wifi?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to connect to wifi with the following code:

```
private static bool ConnectToWifi(string profileName, WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface, Wifi wifi, string profile)
{
    try
    {
        wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profile, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var ex = e;
        return false;
    };
    // Task.Run()

    wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Infrastructure, profileName);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    var status = wifi.ConnectionStatus;
    var x = wlanIface.GetProfileXml(profileName);
    if (status == WifiStatus.Disconnected)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have kept a delay of 5000 ms to ensure the network is connected, but this is causing my UI to not show the loading icon when this code executes.

How I can make my UI also update at same time, instead of waiting for the connection?

Comment: You have to put your logic in a different thread. When you are not starting a new thread your UI thread will be used and the UI can not be updated while your connection logic is running.

Comment: Well if you call `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread ... the UI thread sleeps and doesn't update. If it's thread-safe, move your code to a separate thread - if not, try to find an `async` version.

Comment: On a side-note: *"I have kept a delay of 5000 ms to ensure the network is connected"* Simply waiting a fixed amount of time **does not** ensure it worked. It's a simple workaround that **might** work.

Comment: I just looked it up and `Connect` seems to be the async version. Instead of waiting 5000ms, subscribe to the `WlanConnectionNotification` event and continue your code once that event fires (add `wlanInterface.WlanConnectionNotification += YourMethodHere;` before calling `Connect`).

Comment: i have no idea about how threading works :(

Comment: hi mafred, could you edit it in code itself and post as an answer?

Comment: Btw: If you opt to move it to a different thread, use the `ConnectSynchronously` method instead and remove the `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: @hildasonica I don't have Wifi on my PC so I can't test it, so the code will be more of a "this should work". Will post soon.

Comment: How and where do you call your ConnectToWifi method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

(Both of which make it not possible to return a bool that indicates a successful connection without a bit more logic around it.)

Move your code to a separate thread (if the rest of it is thread-safe) and use the synchronous methods instead:

```
private static void ConnectToWifi(string profileName, WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface, Wifi wifi, string profile)
{
    new Thread(()=>{

        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profile, true);
            wlanIface.ConnectSynchronously(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Infrastructure, profileName, 5000);
            var status = wifi.ConnectionStatus;
            var x = wlanIface.GetProfileXml(profileName);

            result = (status != WifiStatus.Disconnected);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ex = e;
        }
        finally
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{WhateverYouDoWithYourResult(result);}));
        }

    }).Start();
}
```

Or subscribe to the `WlanConnectionNotification` (Not being able to connect might not be seen as a change, so you have to test that):

```
private static bool ConnectToWifi(string profileName, WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface, Wifi wifi, string profile)
{
    try
    {
        wlanIface.WlanConnectionNotification += Interface_ConnectionStateChanged;
        wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profile, true);
        wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Infrastructure, profileName);

        return true; //Just means the attempt was successful, not the connecting itself
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var ex = e;
        return false;
    }
}     

private static void Interface_ConnectionStateChanged(Wlan.WlanNotificationData notifyData, Wlan.WlanConnectionNotificationData connNotifyData)
{
    // Do something with that info, be careful - might not be the same thread as before.
}
```

---

I don't have access to a Wifi right now, so I haven't tested above code. It should work, but you better consider it pseudo-code instead of an actual ready-to-use solution.

Comment: at the end, i need to send the staus based on var status = wifi.ConnectionStatus; so always i am exepecting an output true/false

Comment: @hildasonica You can put that logic in one of the stubs in my example (`Interface_ConnectionStateChanged` or `WhateverYouDoWithYourResult`). Another option would be to make all your logic `async` but since you mentioned you don't know how threads work ... let's just say you shouldn't start with async and tasks before you understand threads (it's a bit more complicated to understand because the compiler does most of the work behind the scenes).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you execute `Thread.Sleep` in the UI thread, you interrupt processing all UI messages, which makes your UI unresponsive. Hence, `Thread.Sleep` and any other long running operations should never be executed in the UI thread.

The solution is to execute these operations in a separate thread to allow the UI thread to continue UI operations. It is generally a good idea to let the UI thread do only UI operations.

In your case it means that the caller should execute the operation in a task:

```
private static bool ConnectToWifi(string profileName, WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface,
    Wifi wifi, string profile, Action<bool> resultCallback, Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    //Your connect code
    bool result;
    if (status == WifiStatus.Disconnected)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    else
    {
        result = true;
    }
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => resultCallback(result));
    return result;
}
```

Another thing: `Thread.Sleep` is not a good idea in task, since you don't know which scheduler you are running on. You should use `Task.Delay` instead. In this case `Thread.Sleep` is generally not a good idea, since you just wait and hope your task is done in five seconds, which is not guaranteed. Also you might simply waste 5 seconds of the user's time in case it connects immediately. The better solution is to use a wait loop and check regularly if the connection is established. If you expect the connection to happen in rather short time, you can use `SpinWait.SpinUntil` (with a timeout of five seconds):

```
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => wifi.ConnectionStatus == WifiStatus.Connected, 5000);
```